# What is the best way to farm Fungi in Genshin Impact? (Efficient and high yield)

Tags: genshin-impact

I need the drops of Fungi, those being Fungal Spores, Luminescent Pollen and Crystalline Cyst Dust. Those materials are required for the ascension and talents of Nahida and Tighnari.

The problem is that their drop rates are very low, and if you use Electro or Pyro against them, you Activate or Scorch them, lowering the drop rates even more to near zero.

What would be the best way to farm Fungi? I'm looking for something time efficient with a higher yield than normal.

Comment: That depends on what characters you have available. Can you add some information about who your main characters are?

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you answered part of the question already.

**Do not use Pyro or Electro AT ALL. Hydro and Cryo are fine. Optionally use Anemo for spread damage**

If you have Ganyu - just use charged shots. Works on most fungi in about 2 shots, and the bloom damage will help if you have multiple foes nearby - only the winged cryo variant will probably take a little longer. Otherwise it depends on your available built characters, just avoid pyro and electro (quite ironic if you are planning to use Nahida with Raiden and Yelan).

Other than that, all you can do is memorize the places that have many fungi nearby. For example, the area just under the Jadeplume *chocobo* has a good amount. Atlas, it is probably faster to check the [interactive official map](https://act.hoyolab.com/ys/app/interactive-map/index.html) and look for areas that you already explored.

Comment: Worth adding pins to your map for locations when you find them, so they're easier to find in-game.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handbook to track fungi, and it shows some spawn points of the mob you are looking for (limited number iirc ) and pin them down in the map and farm the mobs you marked the previous day and then track again so you get new and different spawns
After you complete farming your world join a random world in coop and  farm again . this should be the best method and you can finish farming up for your character of need within a week max.